# Django Rest Framework, some fields are absent when nesting serializers

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

The problem: when I pass `someModelSerializer.data` as a nested data for `anotherModelSerializer`, and after that I pass `anotherModelSerializer.data` to `Response`, in the response I see only two fields of `SomeModel` instead of 5. But when I pass `someModelSerializer.data` directly to `Response`, I can see that all model fields are present.

Details below.

I have **TranslationHistory** model

```
class TranslationHistory(models.Model):
  created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
  updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
  string = models.CharField(max_length=255)
  count = models.IntegerField(default=1)

  user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='translation_history')
```

and it's **TranslationHistorySerializer**

```
class TranslationHistorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

class Meta:
    model = TranslationHistory

user = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True, default=None)
count = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)

def validate_user(self, value):
    return self.context['request'].user

def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    instance.count += 1
    instance.save()
    return instance
```

I also have a virtual entity **Translation**, which is not a model. It has it's own serializer.

```
class TranslationSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
  translation_history = TranslationHistorySerializer() # nested serializer
  translation = serializers.CharField()
```

In my **view**, if I do like this,

```
history = TranslationHistory().findByUserAndString(request.user, string)
historySerializer = TranslationHistorySerializer(history)
return Response(historySerializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

I have the response like this.

```
{
  "id": 18,
  "user": 1,
  "count": 72,
  "created": "2015-07-15T15:35:50.751219Z",
  "updated": "2015-07-24T15:37:04.247469Z",
  "string": "hello"
}
```

**But** if in my **view** I do like this,

```
history = TranslationHistory().findByUserAndString(request.user, string)
historySerializer = TranslationHistorySerializer(history)
serializer = TranslationSerializer(
  data={
         'translation_history': historySerializer.data,
         'translation': 'hello'
       },
  context={'request': request}
)
serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

I have the response like this.

```
{
  "translation_history": {
    "user": 1,
    "string": "hello"
  },
 "translation": "hello"
}
```

Why am I getting only **user** and **string** fields in this case?

Comment: Why are you calling 'is_valid()' during serialization? You should only call that when you are deserializing incoming data.

Comment: Because otherwise I get an exception which says that I must call is_valid() before accessing serializer's data prop

Comment: You're mistaken, that exception will only occur if you pass a data argument to the serializer such as TranslationHistorySerializer(data=request.data)

Comment: Thanks, you are right, I corrected my question. The problem persists, though.